# Getting Error while creating Signal R Hubs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, signalr-hub

I am getting below java script error when i am using signalR for creating Hubs Dynamically. I am using "*jquery.signalR-1.1.2.js*" .

"**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'sending**'"

Below is the Javascript code that is generated automatically.

```
signalR.hub = signalR("/signalr")
        .starting(function () {
            updateClientMembers(signalR);
        })
        .sending(function () {
            var localHubs = [];

            $.each(hubs, function (key) {
                var methods = [];

                $.each(this, function (key) {
                    if (key === "obj") {
                        return true;
                    }

                    methods.push(key);
                });

                localHubs.push({ name: key, methods: methods });
            });

            this.data = window.JSON.stringify(localHubs);
        })
```

Comment: Who is generating the JS automatically? There is no sending function defined for SignalR connections.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sending on the default SignalR connection object, that's what the error is telling you. What is it you're trying to do??